# Report of what Lists or Libraries are using a specific group?

Tags: sharepoint-online, groups

I have several old groups in my site collection and would like to generate a report of the libraries, lists and pages that are using a specific group.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try to below PowerShell commands:

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"

Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
#Variables for Processing
$SiteUrl = "https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename"
$UserName="username"
$Password ="password"

#Setup Credentials to connect

$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName,(ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force))

$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl) 

$Context.Credentials = $credentials


#sharepoint online powershell get all lists

$Lists = $Context.web.Lists

$Context.Load($Lists)

$Context.ExecuteQuery()



#Iterate through each list in a site   

ForEach($List in $Lists)
{

    $Context.Load($List.RoleAssignments)
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()
    Foreach($RoleAssignment in $List.RoleAssignments)
    { 
           $Context.Load($RoleAssignment.Member)

           $Context.executeQuery()

           If($RoleAssignment.Member.PrincipalType -eq "SharePointGroup" -And $RoleAssignment.Member.LoginName -eq "TestGroup"){

                Write-host $List.Title "has TestGroup Group"

            } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll give it a try!

Comment: Would above commands be helpful to you? Comment here if you still need any help.